# Google autocomplete places search error not an instance of HTMLInputElement

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am dynamically creating new input fields when a user clicks on the button. I assign the same attributes to the new input field as inputs where autocomplete is working. For some reason, it always gives the same error: not an instance of HTMLInputElement.

function for creating a new input element, when a user clicks the button:

```
let count = 0;

function addLocationInput ()  {
  count = count + 1;

  let form = document.getElementById("form_location_input");

  const newDiv = document.createElement("input");
  
  
  form.appendChild(newDiv);

  newDiv.setAttribute("style", "position: relative; margin-left: 25px; margin-top: 15px; width: 270px; height: 40px; border-radius: 20px; text-align: center;");
  newDiv.setAttribute("class","form-control form-control-user pac-target-input");
  newDiv.setAttribute("type","text");
  newDiv.setAttribute("id",`next-location-${count}`);
  newDiv.setAttribute("placeholder","Next Location");
  newDiv.setAttribute("name","Next location");
  newDiv.setAttribute("autocomplete","off");

  let nextLocation = document.getElementById(`next-location-˘${count}`)
  let locationAutocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(nextLocation);

}
document.getElementById("add-waypoint").addEventListener("click", addLocationInput);
```

Working input elements:
origin

```
<input style="position: relative; margin-left: 25px; margin-top: 15px; 
width: 270px; height: 40px; border-radius: 20px; text-align: center;" 
class="form-control form-control-user pac-target-input" type="text" 
id="origin-input" placeholder="Origin location" name="origin_location" autocomplete="off">
```

destination

```
<input style="position: relative; margin-left: 25px; margin-top: 15px; 
width: 270px; height: 40px; border-radius: 20px; text-align: center;" 
class="form-control form-control-user pac-target-input" type="text" 
id="destination-input" placeholder="Destination location" name="destination_location" autocomplete="off">
```

and dynamically created input, only this that is created inside of div but I get by the id of input, not div.

```
<div id="form_location_input">
<input style="position: relative; margin-left: 25px; margin-top: 15px; 
width: 270px; height: 40px; border-radius: 20px; text-align: center;" 
class="form-control form-control-user pac-target-input" type="text" 
id="next-location-1" placeholder="Next Location" name="Next location" autocomplete="off"></div>
```

Comment: Here is an obvious typo: `document.getElementById(id="form_location_input");` You should put in the ID of the form.

Comment: oh what a stupid mistake, thank you

Comment: @imvain2 i corrected to document.getElementById("form_location_input"), but error persists

Comment: @imvain2 i was also surprised by this but it turned out that it is fine . I would suggest that you (@vturkovic) should add some breakpoints in the DevTools and rerunning your code. Although i am not sure i suspect that this has to do with `let locationAutocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(nextLocation);`. If the DevTools breakpoints say that the error is created at that specific line of code the the only thing to do is to add an `if(nextLocation)` to check if it exists first and then running that line of code

Comment: i will do that, thanks for advice

Comment: @ΚωνσταντινοςΧαφης i checked with if(nextLocation) and it gives false , so it doesnt exist

Comment: @ΚωνσταντινοςΧαφης i found error, it was here document.getElementById(`next-location-˘${count}`), redundancy quote... stupid mistake, thank you very much for giving me advice to check with if